# Is true damage listed as magic damage in the statistics?

Tags: league-of-legends

So I recently played Vayne and I took a look at the damage statistics after the game. What kind of surprised me was the fact that the statistic showed me that I dealt a small amount of magic damage and as far as I know Vayne has absolutely no spell damage and I also didn't buy any Items that apply on-hit effects (except for BotrK which is physical).

So is True damage = Magic damage? And if not where could this rather small amount of damage come from?

Comment: Who was your support?

Comment: The active on cutlass (but not Botrk) would also deal magic damage

Comment: Small terminology nitpick: spell damage (damage from any spell) is something else than magic damage.

Comment: Moved from answer by LOLNERDZ: "I think lolnexus or kassad.in in the match history it gives some more stats including wards pink and green, true dmg and stuff"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

True damage is not listed on the stat screen at all as far as I know, because it's not physical or magic damage.

The magic damage probably came from your support, or anyone else on your team that can cause you to deal magic damage on hit. Like Leona's Passive or Nami's E.

Comment: Hmm thx good to know. I think it was the passive damage of leona who was my supp.

Comment: True damage is not *specified* on the stat screen, but in theory it does show up as part of your *total* dmg dealt to champions or flat out.

Answer (score 2):

Did you buy a statikk Shiv?  The proc from this should attribute to magic damage.  True damage does not show up in the end game report.

Alternatively, who was your support?  There are some supports that could cause you to have some minor magic damage proc.

Comment: The only item with any/all on-hit effects the OP had was Blade of the Ruined King, so Statikk Shiv couldn't have dealt the damage.

Answer (score 0):

**True damage is applied as magic damage**, but ignoring magic resist or any other type of resistance of the target.

Thats why you see magic damage in the statistics.